# Way to save data from Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have this code here:

The structure from the XML goes like this:

```
public class DatabaseDescriptor
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }        
}

public class Table
{

    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TableName")]
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

How do i loop to get the tables for each database?
How do i add them in a list maybe, keyvalue pair?
so i have the name of the database and also the tables?

Comment: How are you accessing the database, and which database server is it that you are querying?

Comment: @Nattrass, it's all ok, i get all the data, i just want to put them together

Comment: is after deserialization the Tables property correct deserialized?

Comment: yes, it's all ok, now i don't know how to do it, because, i set the data in a datagrid, and it takes the databases, i need the tables too, so how do i put together each database detail to have it's corresponding tables?
In a two dimensional array, maybe a list of keyvaluepair? something?

Comment: @fix_likes_coding, could you please tell me a way to save the data\